# HP laptop running Windows 7 shuts down when the power cable is removed

Tags: laptop, battery

I changed the battery within the last two months on my HP laptop running Windows 7. It shows fully charged, but when the power cable is removed, it dies immediately.

Comment: A few things you can check: Can you run with just the battery? When it dies (when you unplug the cable) does it die as if power has been unplugged, or windows attempted to hibernate/sleep?

Comment: What happens if you keep the power plugged in, but unplug it at the wall?

Answer (score 4):

That is typical failure behavior for a LION battery, the system judges the charge percentage by the voltage drop during charge, and it is no longer charging even with no capacity, tricking the computer into thinking it is at 100% charge, when it is really at 0%.

There may also be corrosion on the battery terminals preventing enough current necessary to run the computer, try cleaning these and doing a cord-pull test at OS pre-boot stage (to prevent data loss) and see if it still shuts off, if it does, replace the battery.